# Worldpay Payment Amount Incorrect

Tags: php, html, xml, decimal, worldpay

In my PHP application I am using the [Worldpay hosted integration](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration) method. I have a html form that when submitted posts xml data to worldpay.

When the form is submitted, their payment page is displayed along with the payment details such as `amount` and `description` etc. The `amount` displayed is correct, however whenever I submit the payment it seems like the amount is incorrect.

My (reduced) html form contains the following ;

```
<form name="my_form" action="xml.php" method="POST">
    // more inputs
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="010">
</form>
```

My (reduced) `xml.php` file contains;

```
// using test environment
$wp_url = "https://secure-test.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp";
$wpXMLusername = 'username';
$wpXMLpass = 'password';
$successURL = "callback.php";

$postXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//Worldpay//DTD Worldpay PaymentService v1//EN" "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="' . $_POST['merchantCode'] . '">
   <submit>
      <order orderCode="' . $_POST['orderCode'] . '" installationId="' . $_POST['instId'] .'">
         <description>' . $_POST['desc'] . '</description>
         <amount currencyCode="' . $_POST['currency'] . '" exponent="2" value="' . $_POST['amount'] . '" /> 
      </order>
   </submit>
</paymentService>';

$curl = curl_init($wp_url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $wpXMLusername . ":" . $wpXMLpass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postXML);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$xmlResult = simplexml_load_string($result);
curl_close($curl);

$errorCode =  (string) $xmlResult->reply->error->attributes()->code[0];

if($errorCode){
    // todo
} else {
    //build URL with result URLs appended
    $redirectUrl = (string) $xmlResult->reply->orderStatus->reference[0];
    $redirectUrl .= "&successURL=$successURL";
    header('Location: '.$redirectUrl.' ');
    exit();
}
```

When I submit the form I am presented with the worldpay payment page which displays;

> Amount (GBP): £0.10

This is all fine so far.

When the worldpay payment page loads I can see in the browser console my `xml.php` file has loaded and the `Form Data` section contains `amount: 010`.

When I submit the form however that payment is being recorded as `10`.

In my `callback.php` which handles the response and writes to my db, at the very top when I `print_r($_REQUEST);` I see;

```
Array
(
    [orderKey] => my-order-key-here
    [paymentStatus] => AUTHORISED
    [paymentAmount] => 10
    [paymentCurrency] => GBP
)
```

I have tried this with various values, e.g. when the html form amount is `487`, the wprldpay payment page displays `£4.87`, however when payment is processed response is `$_REQUEST[paymentAmount] => 487`

I thought it had something to do with the xml data but it's all correct and I have `exponent="2"` set as per the [docs](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/directintegration/paymentrequests#order-details).

This is probably very simple but how can I fix this? Why is the request coming back as `10` and not `010`?

Comment: It's quite normal to represent monetary values in cents or pennies. So "£0.10" is represented as "10" and "£4.87" as "487". This is done because floating point values are not exact, whereas integers are.

Comment: So this is expected behavior? Should I alter the `$_REQUEST[paymentAmount]` in order to convert it into a monetary value again? I will be saving the `$_REQUEST[paymentAmount]` into my database as the value that has been paid. Thanks.

Comment: I'm certainly not surprised by this. However, I have no knowledge of the WorldPay system, and therefore cannot be certain that's what they're doing. That's also why I commented, instead of answering. But it should be somewhere in the docs.